# Why Gunicorn spawn processes running on single cpu core? despite having 8 cores on my system?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I have created 16 workers with gunicorn for the flask app.
why the worker spawn processes all running on cpu 1.

[image]

I have a octa-core processor.
[image]

why the workers not utilizing the all the cores?
or htop command is lying? showing cpu 1 for all processes.
for other multiprocessing tasks I have seen in CPU column values from 1 to 16, and I was expecting here the same the workers distributed from CPU 1 TO 16, or some other fashion. but it is not clear why all workers running on single core?

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you make requests to the workers? Do multiple CPU bars light up? If so, then the work is distributed across your cores just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the WSL (windows subsystem for linux), when this got this issue.
I ran the same program on the AWS EC2 Instance having 8 logical cores.
And got the results, which I was the expecting the in the start.
[image]

here we can see the processes are distributed on all logical cpu cores.

conclusion: WSL "somehow" controls the processes from utilizing all cpu cores.